# I have tried to reset MySQL root password tried 3 ways looking for an alternative? I am using a windows machine the command line

Tags: mysql

I used my windows cmd to go to the location of my MYSQLbin

> C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqld.exe

then navigated to the txt file I had created with the

> C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\my.ini
> --init-file=C:\passwordreset.txt

My first attempt I used the following method.

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost'IDENTIFIED BY 'mypassword';
```

My second attempt I tried using

```
UPDATE mysql.user
    SET authentication_string = PASSWORD('mypassword'), password_expired = 'N'
    WHERE User = 'root' AND Host = 'localhost';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Both did not work. I got in return a txt file when I entered the commands with the following

```
# Other default tuning values
# MySQL Server Instance Configuration File
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Generated by the MySQL Server Instance Configuration Wizard
```

Lastly I have tried

```
mysqld --skip-grant-tables
```

I got this response.

```
2021-08-19T10:41:11.580822Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqld.exe (mysqld 8.0.22) starting as process 6812
2021-08-19T10:41:11.806317Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010091] [Server] Can't create test file C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\data\mysqld_tmp_file_case_insensitive_test.lower-test
2021-08-19T10:41:11.806436Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010091] [Server] Can't create test file C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\data\mysqld_tmp_file_case_insensitive_test.lower-test
2021-08-19T10:41:11.807174Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-013276] [Server] Failed to set datadir to 'C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\data\' (OS errno: 2 - No such file or directory)
2021-08-19T10:41:11.809151Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2021-08-19T10:41:11.839248Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqld.exe: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.22)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
```

Any tips on solving this

Comment: Maybe you need to start this as administrator?

Comment: I am starting as ```Administrator: Command Prompt```

Answer (score -1):

you can uninstall mysql and then install it again and then you can insert your password again with all your databases unharmed